# CakePHP bootstrap array with parameters not translated

Tags: cakephp, translation, bootstrapping

I defined a configuration parameters in bootstrap, but they are not translated after in use.

```
$duedates = array(
    '0'=> __('none'),
    '1'=> __('8 days'),
    '2'=> __('10 days'),
    '3'=> __('15 days'),
    '4'=> __('30 days'),
    '5'=> __('45 days'),
    '6'=> __('60 days'),
    '7'=> __('90 days'),
    '8'=> __('120 days'),
) ;

Configure::write('DUEDATES', $duedates);
```

They aren't trasnlated after using array

```
Configure::read('DUEDATES');
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I don't know CakePHP, but it looks like you simply have not defined translations for the strings `'none'`, `'8 days'`, `'10 days'`, etc. - furthermore I don't understand why your keys are strings, they get converted to ints anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not define translatable strings in your bootstrap, as the language/locale is not yet set at that point. The bootstrap is processed before anything else, including the `Config/core.php`, which is where your language/locale settings should be. You should either:

1. Define the array at a later point, like in the beforeRender method of your AppController.
2. Move the language configuration to your bootstrap prior to defining the translatable strings.

Comment: I made an constants.php file in Config folder and included it after locale definition in beforeFilter in AppController. Know I have file to define constants that should be translated. I do not want to have them in some view or in controller. Project is large and it is good to have some constants defined in separate file.

Answer (score 0):

> ## Bootstrapping CakePHP
>
> If you have any additional configuration needs, use CakePHP’s
>   bootstrap file, found in app/Config/bootstrap.php. This file is
>   executed just after CakePHP’s core bootstrapping.
>
> This file is ideal for a number of common bootstrapping tasks:
>
> - Defining convenience functions.
> - Registering global constants.
> - Defining additional model, view, and controller paths.
> - Creating cache configurations.
> - Configuring inflections.
> - Loading configuration files.
>
> Be careful to maintain the MVC software design pattern when you add
>   things to the bootstrap file: it might be tempting to place formatting
>   functions there in order to use them in your controllers.
>
> Resist the urge. You’ll be glad you did later on down the line.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html

It seems wrong to put localized strings into configuration. Their place seems to be in Views part of MVC.

> CakePHP’s Configure class can be used to store and retrieve
>   application or runtime specific values. Be careful, this class allows
>   you to store anything in it, then use it in any other part of your
>   code: a sure temptation to break the MVC pattern CakePHP was designed
>   for. The main goal of Configure class is to keep centralized variables
>   that can be shared between many objects. Remember to try to live by
>   “convention over configuration” and you won’t end up breaking the MVC
>   structure we’ve set in place.